# GSA - How to fetch documents having <CandidateStatus> meta tag as Empty

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

In GSA collection, I have multiple Candidate profiles. Each profile has various metadata. One of the metadata is CandidateStatus - values(Approved/Available/NotAvailable).
Also there is a big number of Candidate profile who do not have the CandidateStatus meta tag stored in their profile in GSA Collection.

Is there any way I can get those records without using -(minus) inmeta query for other status?

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, why wouldn't you use an inmeta-query with a minus?

You could also look into the GET-param 'requiredfields', which does actually the same as an inmeta-query. Within the 'requiredfields' param, you can use boolean-operators such as a minus and it is possible to do some nesting. Please review the [documentation](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/74/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1077773) for full understanding.